# Rethinkdb, Get value from 1 document then insert the value+1 on another

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

Well i'm trying to do a workaround in RethinkDB trying to make a auto increment secuence. This is what i have:

```
exports.addCar = function (req, res) {
    var car= req.body;
    delete car.id;
    debug('Adding car: %j', car);

    <-Code for Adding new cars->
    r.table('cars').insert(car).run(self.connection, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            debug("[ERROR] addCar %s:%s\n%s", err.name, err.msg, err.message);
            res.send({error: 'An error occurred when adding the new car (' + err.msg + ')'})
        }
        else {
            if(result && result.inserted === 1) {
                car.id = result.generated_keys[0];
                res.send(car);
            }
            else {
                debug("[ERROR] Failed to create new car record: %j (%j)", car, result);
                res.send({error: 'An error occurred when adding the new car document'});
            }
        }
    });

    <-Code for AutoIncrement in another document->
    r.table("autoincrement").get(1).update({
    number: r.row("number").coerceTo("number").add(1).coerceTo("string")}).run(self.connection, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            debug("[ERROR] findById: %s:%s\n%s", err.name, err.msg, err.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log("New record added");
        }
    })
};
```

As you can see, Every time a car is saved this adds a +1 to the "number" row in another document for the auto increment sequence.

How can i take the result from the other document to update a field into the car row?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer ^_^

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your realization you need 3 operation.

Better:

1) Update `autoincrement` table and return changes (check [update doc](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/update/)):

```
r.table("autoincrement").get(1).update({
    number: r.row("number").coerceTo("number").add(1).coerceTo("string")}, {
            returnChanges: true
        }).run(self.connection, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            debug("[ERROR] findById: %s:%s\n%s", err.name, err.msg, err.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log("New record added");
        }
    })
```

In `result.changes[0].new_val.number` you will have incremented value.

2) Update your `car` object with this number (or whatever), and insert result into `cars` table.